# How to add multiple service inside provider if mock tests are used ? : Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm facing some issue regarding testing in Angular 2. Here is my code snippet:

*app.component.spec.ts*

```typescript
import { KnowledgeServiceApi } from "../knowledgeapi.service";
import { SpeechSynthesisService } from "../speech-synthesis.service";

providers: [
  {provide: KnowledgeServiceApi, useValue: MockKnowledgeApi }
]
```

The error I'm getting: `No provider for SpeechSynthesisService`

When I try to do this:

```typescript
providers: [
  {provide: KnowledgeServiceApi, SpeechSynthesisService, useValue: MockKnowledgeApi }
]
```

Still I get error. How should I solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to use the same mock your providers array should look like:

```js
providers: [
  { provide: KnowledgeServiceAp, useValue: MockKnowledgeApi },
  { provide: SpeechSynthesisService, useValue: MockKnowledgeApi }
]
```

But I recommend using a different one like this:

```js
providers: [
  { provide: KnowledgeServiceAp, useValue: MockKnowledgeApi },
  { provide: SpeechSynthesisService, useValue: MockSpeechSynthesisService }
]
```